# Antlr Main Class Error: MyListener cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, antlr4

I have an antlr4 based project with a Main class containing this code:

```
package com.progur.langtutorial;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

public class Main {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            CharStream input = CharStreams.fromString("test");  

            GYOOLexer lexer = new GYOOLexer(input);
            GYOOParser parser = new GYOOParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
            parser.addParseListener(new MyListener());

            // Start parsing
            parser.program(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

However, I am having an error in parser.addParseListener(new MyListener()); where it says `MyListener cannot be resolved to a type`. What could that mean? In every tutorial I looked there was a random name for where 'MyListener()' is. What should be the correct statement for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The listener that you pass to `addParseListener` should be a class that you defined yourself (and which implements the `GYOOListener` interface or extends the `GYOOBaseListener` abstract class generated by ANTLR). If you did not define a listener class, there's no reason to call `addParseListener`.

Comment: This is probably the case, or else s/he defined it in some other package than `com.progur.langtutorial`